# Meta-analysis_studies with within and between study design

Tags: multilevel-analysis, meta-analysis

I am trying to run a meta analysis based on the question if physical activity leads to an increase in cognitive functioning.

I have studies that report mean and standard deviations for the experimental group and control group, both at pretest and at posttest.

My question is - what would be the accurate way to perform this meta analysis?
I have the option to calculate cohens d from the posttests. But I could also use just the means of the pre and posttrest of the experimental group and calculate cohens d, based on the change score.

Would it be possible to use both Cohens d in one meta-analysis (maybe through multilevel meta analysis or multivariate meta-analysis)?